# Is 'take out' phrase idiomatic in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I am in airplane, my luggage is in the overhead compartment and very heavy. I want to request the person adjacent to me

> If you don't mind, can you please **take out** my bag from the overhead compartment?

Is the phrase **take out** natural for the native speakers? If not, what is the natural way to say this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you're speaking to someone standing between you and the compartment. We'd be more likely to say something like:

> (*pointing) Would you mind handing me my bag ? *or*
>   Could I ask you to hand me my bag ... ?

This puts just a tiny bit more emphasis on the fact that the other person is doing something helpful for you and a tiny bit less emphasis on the effort involved.

I doubt the words *overhead compartment* would come into it, since you'd have to indicate, one way or another, which bag is yours. You might use something like "from up there" if you had to redirect the other person's look.

Answer (score 4):

That's a hard question to answer. All I can say for sure is that it's not natural for me. I'd say "Please **take my bag from** the overhead compartment" or "Please **take my bag out of** the overhead compartment".

All native speakers have their own idiolect, their own ways of saying things. There isn't only a single ***natural*** way to say everything in English or any other language. Some expressions are fixed, but even those are often spoken and written in different ways by people who've learned them in different ways.

I wouldn't blink if I heard an American or a Brit say "Please **take out my bag from** the overhead compartment". I'd think of it as natural native-speaker English, just not mine.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Bill: "Please take X out of the Y" sounds more natural than "Please take out X from the Y", but not so much so that the latter sounds terrible in conversation.

Also, if you omit where the item is taken from, then the words *take out* sound more natural together. For example, I can imagine a teacher saying,

> Please take out your pencils and put your books on the floor under your seat.

but,

> Please take a pencil out of your desk.

sounds better (more natural) to me than,

> Please take out a pencil from your desk.